# Form attribute is not nil but getting First form attribute can't be nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm getting an error on my edit user modal that says that the first argument can't be nil; however, the form works and pulls the information as expected. The setup is like this:
1) I have a table that summarizes employees
2) each employee has a modify action
3) the modify action opens up a modal with the edit form

The form works and users are able to edit employees. However, every time it's open I get an internal error notification saying that the first argument can't be nil or empty. just to be sure, I'm displaying the employee name in the edit modal to confirm it's not nil (and it's not). The problem is, I'm getting notifications for internal server errors caused by this issue although somehow the form is working.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Employee table code:

```
    <tr>
    <td> <%= employee.name %> </td>
    <td> <%= employee.status ? t(:active) : t(:inactive) %> </td>
    <td> <%= mmm_dd_yy_date(employee.created_at) %> </td>
    <td> <%= mmm_dd_yy_date(employee.updated_at) %> </td>
    <td> <%= link_to t(:edit), '#', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#EditModal_#{employee.id}", "data-remote" => edit_employee_path(employee) + "#modal-edit-form" %> | 
  <%= link_to t(:remove), employee, method: :delete, data: { confirm: t(:confirm_remove_employee, name: employee.name)} %>
     <!-- Modal -->
      <div id='<%= "EditModal_#{employee.id}" %>' class="modal fade" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title"><%= t(:edit_employee) %></h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body"> 
             <%=render partial: 'edit_form', locals: {employee: employee} %>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><%= t(:close) %></button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Form modal code:

```
<div id= "modal-edit-form">
  <%= employee.name %>
<%=form_for(employee) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class = "row" >
    <div class = "col-xs-6">
      <%= f.label :name%>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.label :status %>
      <%= f.collection_select :status, {true: t(:yes), false: t(:no)}, :first, :last, selected: employee.status %>
      <%= f.submit t(:update), class: "btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: showing the full error would be very helpful, including backtrace. I don't think it's coming from this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks good to me.

--

The one thing I would say is that including `form_for` multiple times on the same page is a big no-no - a bunch of conflicts will occur (`id` etc).

I would personally move the functionality to your `employees#edit` action as ajax:

```
#app/controllers/employees_controller.rb
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html, :json, only: :edit
   def edit
      @employee = Employee.find params[:id]
      respond_with @employee
   end
end 

#app/views/employees/edit.js.erb
$("<%=j render 'edit' %>").appendTo("body");
// fire modal

#app/views/employees/edit.html.erb
<div id='<%= "EditModal_#{employee.id}" %>' class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title"><%= t(:edit_employee) %></h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body"> 
         <%=render partial: 'edit_form', locals: {employee: @employee} %>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><%= t(:close) %></button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

#app/views/employees/index.html.erb
<%= link_to t(:edit), '#', data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#EditModal_#{employee.id}", remote: edit_employee_path(employee) + "#modal-edit-form" }, remote: true %>
```

This way, you'll only be appending the `edit` forms when you render them.

Comment: That's a great point, itay actually be what's causing the issue. I'll give that a shot. Thank you

Comment: Keep me posted - I'm as interested to fix this as you

Comment: Rich, it looks like this did fix the issue; however, with the code above I wasn't getting the edit action to trigger or the modal to show, so this is what I ended up doing:   edit.js.erb => $("<%=j render 'edit' %>").appendTo("body");
$('.modal').modal('show')   Call to edit action:      <%= link_to t(:edit), edit_employee_path(employee), data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#EditModal_#{employee.id}", remote: edit_employee_path(employee) + "#modal-edit-form" }, remote: true %>